# Como enviar um json via post com PHP?

Tags: php, json, libcurl

Bom pessoal,

**preciso enviar um json via post para uma API (URL: https://www.bitcointoyou.com/Payments/) e ler o que retornar? Como posso fazer? Pensei em algo com cURL.**

Grato

Comment: `CURL -X POST -H "Cookie: seu_cookie=valor;" -d "{seu json}" https://www.bitcointoyou.com/Payments/`, agora basta converter isto para o PHP, que tem vários e várias postagem por aí. A pergunta como está não diz o que tem que ser enviado, esta página é protegia, somente com conta pode acessar, então é impossível analisar, *não vou criar uma conta só para isso*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro você deve instanciar um array com os campos que você quer enviar:

```
$array = array("cor" => "vermelho", "ano" => "2012");
```

Depois terá que usar a função json_encode para gerar o JSON:

```
$json = json_encode($array);
```

A chamada da função CURL deve ficar assim:

```
$ch = curl_init('URL_DA_CHAMADA');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json))                                                                       
);
```

O tratamento do retorno da chamada deve acontecer na variável que está recebendo o resultado do curl_exec, caso o retorno seja um JSON também, você deve usar a função json_decode.

```
$jsonRet = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
```

Answer (score 1):

A página é protegida para usuário conectados, portanto muito possivelmente precisará enviar os cookies da sessão (*o nome da sessão, aparentemente, é `ASP.NET_SessionId`*), uma forma simplista é utilizar:

```
$cabeçalho = ['Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=' . $ValorSessao];
```

Além disso por ser um website de uma *exchange* de bitcoin deve exigir que utilize um UA válido, portanto, também utilize um User-Agent válido.

---

Defina o método POST:

```
CURLOPT_POST => true
```

Além disso defina o que vai enviar:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $ConteudoQueQuerEnviar
```

---

Logo:

```
$ConteudoPOST = json_encode($sua_array);
$ConteudoCabecalho = [
    'Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'
]
```

Definido isto utilize o CURL:

```
$curl = curl_init('https://www.bitcointoyou.com/Payments/');

curl_setopt_array($curl, [

    //-------- Segurança (caso se preocupe com isto):
    // Verifica o SSL (dificultar MITM):        
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 2,

    // Limita o CURL para o protocolo HTTPS (dificultar SSRF e "downgrade"):
    CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTPS,

    // Limita para não seguir redirecionamento (mesmo motivo acima):
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 0,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 0,

    // Define um Tempo limita (dificultar DoS por Slow HTTP):
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 1,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 3,
    CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT => 750,
    CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME => 1,        
    //--------

    // Define como método POST:
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,

    // Define o JSON (o corpo do POST):
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $ConteudoPOST,

    // Define o cabeçalho:
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $ConteudoCabecalho,

    // Define para retornar o conteúdo para a variável:
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
]);

$RespostaCURL = curl_exec($curl);
```